# initial Flutter iOS app does not start on Flutter 3.16

Tags: ios, flutter

I just updated my Flutter to 3.16. Now all my iOS apps are stuck on the starting white screen. I tried to create a new app with `flutter create test_new_project` and it stuck on the white screen too. This is the result of the flutter doctor command:

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.16.0, on macOS 14.1.1 23B81 darwin-arm64, locale
    en-BG)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 34.0.0)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 15.0.1)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 2022.3)
[✓] Android Studio (version 2021.1)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.64.2)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.84.2)
[✓] Connected device (3 available)
[✓] Network resources

• No issues found!
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Try running the following command from the project root `flutter build ios —-release`

Comment: Did you start the command at all?

Comment: on your IDE (Android Studio, Visual Studio Code) while you have your project open expand terminal window at the bottom and run the command

Comment: it should be `flutter run --release` but this does not solve my problem with the debug, but at least I am able to start the app.

Comment: Thank for the comment I edited my answer.. Try delete build folder and run again the project. It will re-generate the files from the beginning

Answer (score 1):

If this happens on a device running iOS 12, then it's caused by a known issue. See https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/138711 and https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/135317. So I think your options are to wait for a fix or downgrade to Flutter 3.13.9.

Comment: device is iOS 17